# Can docker for Windows run inside a Windows Guest (VM) running on ESXi?

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

Our build system is a win 10 virtual machine, running on an ESXi host (we have two ESXi boxes, and I see they are on diff versions of ESXi, which we will shortly get in sync!):

- VMware ESXi, 6.5.0, 7967591
- VMware ESXi, 6.7.0, 8169922
- Dell Poweredge R640

**Question 1:** We want the build system to run docker (docker for windows, part of Windows 10) to create Windows containers with our app pieces in them (windows services) as part of the build.

**Question 2:** We also want the build system to run docker (docker for Windows, part of Windows 10) to create Linux containers for the Linux based parts of our app, as part of the build.

Is this possible?

Comment: By chance do you actually mean ESXi?  If that’s the case what’s the version.  Please supply this vital information in an edit to your question

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, OP improved with that detail.

Comment: Do both versions support nested virtualization?  Does the version you plan to use support it?

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry, I am not following you. My questions are just questions. If they are lacking needed detail, I am happy to add.

Comment: I am asking if you have confirmed if ESXi 6.7.0 supports nested virtualization.  If it does not then what you want is not possible.  You want to run Docker within a VMWare virtual machines, which means Hyper-V within those Virtual machines must be enabled, which means ESXi must support nested virtualization.  Please provide this required information by modifying your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Apologies, I do not know the answer to your question. While it may relate to the OP, the OP is just what it is, a question.

Comment: I was able to confirm ESXi 6.7.0 supports nested virtualization, provides you enable *Expose hardware-assisted virtualization to the guest OS*, then you can enable Hyper-V on the Windows installation and install Docker.

Comment: I know you can do it with ESXi 7.0, as I am doing it right now.